# How do I install linux steam games on a USB?

Tags: steam, linux

I know that to do this, I must go to steam settings, download, and make a new steam library on the USB. The problem is that my /media does not have a drop down and if I select /media it says "selected folder must be empty."
I'd like to know how to get steam to recognize my flash drive so I can install games there.

Comment: Which version of steam are you running?

Answer (score 2):

As I know that, you can go to Settings -> Downloads then click on Steam Library Folders
Then you can add folders wherever you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`/media` should have a selectable subfolder when the drive is plugged in, `/media` istelf is a part of the parent filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

To go before @DrKNa's answer,

This looks as though your linux box is not recognizing the drive. Depending on the OS (SteamOS is an offshoot of Ubuntu which is derived from Debian which is what I am most familiar with.), you could run `lsusb` when the drive is plugged in, if you get a response that has the manufacturer of the drive then the kernel has recognized it.

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID XXXX:XXXX MANUFACTURER DEVICE
```

At this point, `ls /dev/sd*` should list your main

```
/dev/sda   /dev/sda2  /dev/sdb  /dev/sdd    /dev/sde
/dev/sda1  /dev/sda5  /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc
```

Now `cd /mnt; mkdir usb; sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/usb/`. This will mount the drive in `/mnt`.

Alternatively, Insert the drive into the usb slot and run `dmesg` in a terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+T`) and your system will output kernel messages to the screen, the last line should be something about the usb device.

```
[232637.544579] usb 1-1.5.2: New USB device found
```